How to supply a certificate while creating a linked service to presto in Azure Datafactory
I am trying to connect to Presto using linked service in Azure Data Factory using the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-presto?tabs=data-factory
I have entered the credentials and the certificate used for authenticating with Presto

I have the certificate as a .jks file. How do i pass the certificate to the linked service above ?

The full path of the .jks file containing trusted CA certificates for verifying the server when connecting over TLS. This property can only be set when using TLS on self-hosted IR. The default value is the cacerts.jks file installed with the IR.

According to this MS document

trustedCertPath property can only be set when using TLS on self-hosted IR.

You should create self-hosted integration runtime and connect presto server with it. Provide The full path of the .jks file containing trusted CA certificates for verifying the server when connecting over TLS. The default value is the cacerts.jks file installed with the IR.
Configure linked service as shown below:

